# $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof of this multivariable limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

We've to prove that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2} =0
$$

Kindly check if my proof below is correct.

**Proof**

We need to show there exists $\delta>0$ for an $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
\left| \frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \right| < \varepsilon \implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2}< \delta
$$

Start
$$
\left| \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} \right| <\left| \frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \right| < \varepsilon
$$

Note
$$
\left| \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} \right|= \frac{x^2|x|}{x^2+y^2}>\frac{(x^2-y^2)|x|}{x^2+y^2}
$$

Therefore
$$
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}|x|<\varepsilon \tag{1}
$$

Note
$$
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}|x|<|x|=\sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta
$$

So
$$
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}|x|<\delta \tag{2}
$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can say
$$
\delta=\varepsilon
$$

Comment: Your implication is in the wrong order. You want $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies\dots$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews gotcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not correct. You are supposed to find, for each $\varepsilon>0$, some $\delta>0$ such that$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies\left|\frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\right|<\varepsilon,$$and that's not what you did.

Note that$$\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|=|x|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant|x|$$and that$$\left|\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}\right|=y^2\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant y^2\leqslant|y|$$if $y\in[-1,1]$. So, take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon2\right\}$. Then, if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, then $y\in[-1,1]$ and $|x|,|y|<\delta\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2$, and therefore$$\left|\frac{x^3+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leqslant|x|+|y|<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: How about $$\left| \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|= \frac{x^2|x|}{x^2+y^2}<|x|<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$$  and hence $\delta=\varepsilon$?

Comment: I did use that, implicitly. If I did not know that $|x|,|y|\color{red}\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, I would not have written that $|x|+|y|<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2$.

Comment: Alright I got it now

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple strategy for dealing with such limits, which is just switching to polar coordinates.
 By setting $x=\rho\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\theta$ we have $x^2+y^2=\rho^2$ and

$$ \left|\frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\right| = \rho\left|\cos^3\theta+\rho \sin^4\theta\right|. $$
The RHS is trivially bounded by $\rho(1+\rho)$, which is $\leq 2\rho$ if $\rho\leq 1$.
It follows that as long as $\rho\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\leq 1$ we have $|f(x,y)|\leq \varepsilon$.

---

If you want a sharp bound you may consider that for any sufficiently small $\rho\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the maximum of $|\cos^3\theta+\rho\sin^4\theta|$ is indeed $1$, so $\rho\leq\varepsilon$ is sufficient to ensure $|f(x,y)|\leq\varepsilon$.

Comment: Or alternatively, $\delta=\min(\epsilon/2,1).$

Comment: How about $$\left| \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|= \frac{x^2|x|}{x^2+y^2}<|x|<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$$  and hence $\delta=\varepsilon$?

Comment: You still have to consider the term $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}$, so it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa “And hence $\ delta=\epsilon.$ That gets this sort of proof backwards. You can’t prove $\delta=\epsilon,$ because any positive $\delta<\epsilon$ works, too. What you can say is $\delta=\epsilon$ works.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Agreed. That's what I meant too. It's just that i didn't mention it in the comment. I understand that we can call it a day when we find some $\delta$ that works.